# Not able to fetch data from database

Tags: scala, slick

When I run my program the first time, data get inserted into the table, and it works as intended.

Now please comment the call to the `setUp(db)` method and run this. This will not print the rows present in `db`. Why doesn't the future ever get completed and print the rows in the table?

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Double)](tag, "COFFEES")                         
{
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def * = (name, price)
}

object Main extends App {
  val db = Database.forConfig("mydb")
  *setUp(db)*
  query(db)
  def setUp(db: Database) = {
    val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
    val setup = DBIO.seq(coffees.schema.create, coffees += ("rohit", 100))
    val setUpFuture = db.run(setup)
    Await.result(setUpFuture, Duration.Inf)
  }

  def query(db: Database) = {
    val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
    val q = for (c <- coffees) yield c.*
    val a = q.result
    val f: Future[Seq[(String, Double)]] = db.run(a)
    f.onComplete {
      lst => {
        for(e <-lst) println(s"${e}")
      }
    }
    Await.ready(f, 100 second)
  }

  def queryWithStreams(db: Database) = {
    val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
    val query = for(c <- coffees) yield c.name
    val p: DatabasePublisher[String] = db.stream(query.result)
    p.foreach { s => println(s"Element: $s") }
  }
}
```

Comment: when I do db.close after the await.result then it works fine i.e. prints the list.
why this is happening so. Same used to work in java.

Comment: what is your db connection / settings? it worked for me just like this with a mysql db.

Comment: Hi @ossip
    mydb = {
   dataSourceClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
    properties = {
    databaseName = "test"
    user = "root"
    password = "root"
    }
    numThreads = 10
    }

Comment: Looks fine to me. Did you check, Is the entry in the database after you run it with setup? Best drop the table first to make sure it's working.